# I'm new to python.. I'm getting "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'" for count inside while loop

Tags: python

```
Sample input : a2b4c1d2e1
Output: "aabbbbcdde"

str1 = "a2b4c1d2e1"
str2 = ""
data = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

for x in range(0,len(str1)):
    if str1[x] in data:
        print str1[x]
        count = str1[x+1]
        print count
        while count >= 0:
            str2 = str2 + str1[x]
            print "str2", str2
            count = count - 1
            print "inside while", count

print "output", str2
```

I'm new to python, can someone please tell shed some light how to fix this error "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'"

Comment: Use `count = int(str1[x+1])` to convert from char (string) to int

Comment: You assign str[x+1] to count. str[x+1] is definitely a letter based on your code. So it crashes when you say count = count - 1 since it can't figure out what "a" - 1 means, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what the error message is telling you. You are trying to subtract a string and an integer, which is obviously an error.

When you do `count = str1[x+1]`, you are assigning a character to the variable `count`. Note that the character '1' is not the same thing as the number 1. If you want `count` to hold a number instead of a string you'll need to convert it first, so changing line 16 to

```
count = int(count) - 1
```

should fix your error.

I'm not sure if I explained it correctly, so please ask again if you didn't understand the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I got it, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

First, the line `count = str1[x+1]` is not working as you intended. What you are storing is a char variable, not an integer. So you may want to typecast it to int if you really want to use it, however, I recommend you to write a for loop that increments by 2 at a time.